# After upgrading to Ubuntu 17.04 several programs such as calibre and my epub reader stopped working

Tags: upgrade, 17.04, gtk, ibus

tony@tony-desktop:~$ calibre-debug -g
calibre 3.3  embedded-python: True is64bit: True
Linux-4.10.0-26-generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid Linux ('64bit', 'ELF')
('Linux', '4.10.0-26-generic', '#30-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 27 09:30:12 UTC 2017')
Python 2.7.12
Linux: ('debian', 'stretch/sid', '')
Interface language: None
Successfully initialized third party plugins: DeDRM (6, 0, 8) && Kindle Collections (1, 7, 15)
Turning on automatic hidpi scaling
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.

(calibre-debug:5005): Gtk-WARNING **: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)

(calibre-debug:5005): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed

(calibre-debug:5005): Gtk-WARNING **: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)

(calibre-debug:5005): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed

(calibre-debug:5005): Gtk-WARNING **: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)

(calibre-debug:5005): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed
devicePixelRatio: 1.0
logicalDpi: inf x inf
physicalDpi: -71771164.0253 x -121213521.465
Using calibre Qt style: True

tony@tony-desktop:~$ calibre
    GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.

```
(calibre:3502): Gtk-WARNING **: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)

(calibre:3502): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed

(calibre:3502): Gtk-WARNING **: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)

(calibre:3502): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed

(calibre:3502): Gtk-WARNING **: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)

(calibre:3502): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed
```

if I try with root permissions:

```
tony@tony-desktop:~$ sudo calibre
[sudo] password for tony: 
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 405, resource id: 0, major code: 1 (CreateWindow), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 406, resource id: 83886084, major code: 2 (ChangeWindowAttributes), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 407, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 408, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 409, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 411, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 412, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 413, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 416, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 420, resource id: 83886084, major code: 2 (ChangeWindowAttributes), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 421, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 422, resource id: 83886084, major code: 19 (DeleteProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 423, resource id: 83886084, major code: 20 (GetProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 427, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 428, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 431, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 434, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 435, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 436, resource id: 83886084, major code: 12 (ConfigureWindow), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 452, resource id: 83886084, major code: 2 (ChangeWindowAttributes), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 453, resource id: 83886084, major code: 2 (ChangeWindowAttributes), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 454, resource id: 83886084, major code: 20 (GetProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 455, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 456, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 457, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 458, resource id: 83886084, major code: 20 (GetProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 459, resource id: 83886084, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 460, resource id: 83886084, major code: 20 (GetProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 461, resource id: 83886084, major code: 19 (DeleteProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 462, resource id: 83886084, major code: 8 (MapWindow), minor code: 0
QWidget::setMaximumSize: (/JobError) Negative sizes (16777215,-492131604) are not possible
DBusExport: Failed to connect to DBUS session bus, with error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: dbus-launch: /opt/calibre/lib/libdbus-1.so.3: version `LIBDBUS_PRIVATE_1.10.10' not found (required by dbus-launch)

QFont::setPointSize: Point size <= 0 (-1), must be greater than 0
QFont::setPointSize: Point size <= 0 (-1), must be greater than 0
QFont::setPointSize: Point size <= 0 (-1), must be greater than 0
QFont::setPointSize: Point size <= 0 (-1), must be greater than 0
QFont::setPointSize: Point size <= 0 (-1), must be greater than 0
QFont::setPointSize: Point size <= 0 (-1), must be greater than 0
QFont::setPointSize: Point size <= 0 (-1), must be greater than 0
QFont::setPointSize: Point size <= 0 (-1), must be greater than 0
QWidget::setMinimumSize: (MainWindow/Main) The largest allowed size is (16777215,16777215)
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 464, resource id: 0, major code: 1 (CreateWindow), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 465, resource id: 83886092, major code: 2 (ChangeWindowAttributes), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 466, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 467, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 468, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 470, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 471, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 472, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 473, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 477, resource id: 83886092, major code: 2 (ChangeWindowAttributes), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 478, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 479, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 480, resource id: 83886092, major code: 20 (GetProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 484, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 485, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 488, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 489, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 492, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 493, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 494, resource id: 83886092, major code: 12 (ConfigureWindow), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 495, resource id: 83886092, major code: 2 (ChangeWindowAttributes), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 496, resource id: 83886092, major code: 2 (ChangeWindowAttributes), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 497, resource id: 83886092, major code: 20 (GetProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 498, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 499, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 500, resource id: 83886092, major code: 19 (DeleteProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 501, resource id: 83886092, major code: 20 (GetProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 502, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 503, resource id: 83886092, major code: 20 (GetProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 504, resource id: 83886092, major code: 19 (DeleteProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 505, resource id: 83886092, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 506, resource id: 83886092, major code: 8 (MapWindow), minor code: 0
QWidget::setMinimumSize: (MainWindow/Main) The largest allowed size is (16777215,16777215)
QWidget::setMinimumSize: (MainWindow/Main) The largest allowed size is (16777215,16777215)
QWidget::setMinimumSize: (MainWindow/Main) The largest allowed size is (16777215,16777215)
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 509, resource id: 83886084, major code: 10 (UnmapWindow), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 512, resource id: 83886084, major code: 4 (DestroyWindow), minor code: 0
QWidget::setMinimumSize: (MainWindow/Main) The largest allowed size is (16777215,16777215)
^CQWidget::setMinimumSize: (MainWindow/Main) The largest allowed size is (16777215,16777215)
QWidget::setMinimumSize: (MainWindow/Main) The largest allowed size is (16777215,16777215)
```

Comment: As mentioned in another post, these are warnings and not errors:  I get the same warnings on my system, yet calibre runs (well, I presume).   What are some of the other programs which are not operational on your system?

Comment: Charles thanks for the reply. On my system calibre does not work. In the GUI the icon blinks a few times and then nothing. From the terminal I get the warnings and then nothing.

Comment: Are thre other programs which also fail to open?

Comment: my Ebook Viewer fails to open

Comment: I think that's part of Calibre

Comment: try the following:  In a terminal, enter `calibre-debug -g` copy the output and paste it into your question

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Calibre to work by starting it with the following:

```
Sudo QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=1 nohup calibre &
```

I also made other changes that may or may not have affected this allowing it to start such as changing the library.png to 256x256 from 1024x1024.